# MongoDB: Set value in collection depending on other object

Tags: mongodb

### Problem

A document looks like this:

```
{
  data: [
    { identifier: 'a', value: 10 },
    { identifier: 'b', value: 53 },
    { identifier: 'c', value: 16 }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to set all values to `null` if another object inside the same array with identifier `x` meets a condition. Real life example:

If property `value` of object with identifier `a` is greater than `9`, set property `value` of objects with identifier `b` or `c` to `null`.

### Approach

I'm trying it with a `$project` pipeline but don't know how to find other objects.

```
// ... Rest
{
$unwind: '$data'
}, {
$project: {
  data: {
    identifier: 1,
    value: {
      $cond: {
        if: {}, // Implement
        then: null, // Only valid for current value
        else: '$row.value'
      }
    }
  }
}
// ... Rest
```

### Wanted output

The resulting aggregation should be an array.

If the value of `a` respects the condition:

```
[
  { data: { identifier: 'a', value: null } },
  { data: { identifier: 'b', value: null } },
  { data: { identifier: 'c', value: null } },
  // ... more documents
]
```

If the value of `a` doesn't respect the condition:

```
[
  { data: { identifier: 'a', value: 10 } },
  { data: { identifier: 'b', value: 53 } },
  { data: { identifier: 'c', value: 16 } },
  // ... more documents
]
```

Comment: No,  it should stay untouched. So, input and output are basically the same, but the `value` might be `null`.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you.

Comment: Well, it was not. I'm sorry. The result should be an array. I updated it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

Use [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) expression with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to verify if the input condition matches any element in array and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to output the length for [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) than 0 comparison; if yes use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to map all the values to null; if no keep the data value as is.

```
 db.colname.aggregate({"$addFields":{
  "data":{
    "$cond":[
      {"$gt":[
        {"$size":{
          "$filter":{
            "input":"$data",
            "as":"d",
            "cond":{
              "$and":[
                {"$eq":["a","$$d.identifier"]}, 
                {"$gt":["$$d.value", 9]}
              ]
            }
          }
        }}, 
        0
      ]}, 
      {"$map":{
        "input":"$data",
        "as":"d",
        "in":{ "identifier": "$$d.identifier", "value": null }
      }}, 
      "$data"
    ]
  }
}})
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm using it now but with `$project` instead of `$addFields`, so I don't need to add a new field.

Answer (score 1):

try this aggregation, without using `$unwind`

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {
        index : {$indexOfArray : ["$data.identifier", "a"]},
        isTrue : {$gte : [{$arrayElemAt : ["$data.value", {$indexOfArray : ["$data.identifier", "a"]}]}, 10]}
        }},
    {$addFields : {
        row : {
            identifier : {$arrayElemAt : ["$data.identifier", "$index"]},
            value : {$cond : ["$isTrue", {$arrayElemAt : ["$data.value", "$index"]}, null]}
        }
    }},
    {$project : {index :0, isTrue : 0, data : 0}}
]).pretty()
```

result

```
> db.col.aggregate([ {$addFields : { index : {$indexOfArray : ["$data.identifier", "a"]}, isTrue : {$gte : [{$arrayElemAt : ["$data.value", {$indexOfArray : ["$data.identifier", "a"]}]}, 10]} }}, {$addFields : { row : { identifier : {$arrayElemAt : ["$data.identifier", "$index"]}, value : {$cond : ["$isTrue", {$arrayElemAt : ["$data.value", "$index"]}, null]} } }}, {$project : {index :0, isTrue : 0, data : 0}} ]).pretty()

{ "_id" : 1, "row" : { "identifier" : "a", "value" : 10 } }
>
```

**EDIT**

use `$map` to set values to all identifier's value

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$addFields : { 
        isTrue : {$gte : [{$arrayElemAt : ["$data.value", {$indexOfArray : ["$data.identifier", "a"]}]}, 10]}
    }},
    {$addFields : {
        data : 
            {$map : {
                input : "$data",
                as : "d",
                in : {
                    identifier : "$$d.identifier",
                    value : {$cond : ["$isTrue", "$$d.value", null]}
                }
            }}
    }},
    {$project : {_id :0, isTrue : 0}}
]).pretty()
```

result

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "identifier" : "a",
            "value" : 10
        },
        {
            "identifier" : "b",
            "value" : 53
        },
        {
            "identifier" : "c",
            "value" : 16
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my example wasn't complete. The result should be an array with all documents. I updated the example!

Comment: @Julian updated answer to update all identifier's values

Comment: That looks promising. I need `$unwind` for a later `$group` but I could do it after it.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between these two approaches (before and after "EDIT")? The solution with `$map` looks better to me.

Comment: Before edit is to return only the matched row, after edit we used `$map` to modify all row values based on the condition